# CS50P Introduction to Programming. Problem Set 4 Problem "Little Professor"

Tags: python, cs50

I am trying to get my program to pass the automated test "Little Professor generates 10 problems before exiting" but I keep gettin the error "Cause: timed out while waiting for program to exit". I have checked that the program handles edge cases, non-integer inputs, and it always exits after 10 problems. Am I missing something something obvious?

Here is my code:

```
import random
import sys

def main():
    op1_list = []
    op2_list = []
    score = 0
    level = get_level()

    for i in range(10):
        OP1 = generate_integer(level)
        OP2 = generate_integer(level)

        while OP1 in op1_list:
            OP1 = generate_integer(level)

        while OP2 in op2_list:
            OP2 = generate_integer(level)

        ans = OP1 + OP2
        op1_list.append(OP1)
        op2_list.append(OP2)
        print(OP1, "+", OP2, "= ",end="")

        for n in range(3):
            try:
                user_ans = int(input())
                if user_ans == ans:
                    score += 1
                    break
                else:
                    print("EEE")
                    print(OP1, "+", OP2, "= ",end="")
                    if n == 2:
                        print(OP1, "+", OP2, "=",ans)
                        break
            except ValueError:
                print("EEE")
                print(OP1, "+", OP2, "= ",end="")
                if n == 2:
                    print(ans)
                    break

    print(f"Score: {score}")
    sys.exit()

def get_level():
    while True:
        print("Level: ",end="")
        try:
            level = int(input())
            if (level > 3):
                raise ValueError
            elif (level < 1):
                raise ValueError
            else:
                return level
        except ValueError:
            pass

def generate_integer(level):
    match level:
        case 1:
            return random.randint(0,9)
        case 2:
            return random.randint(10,99)
        case 3:
            return random.randint(100,999)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It fails because you filter out operands if they were already used.

Basically if you will remove the following section, the checks pass.

```py
while OP1 in op1_list:
  OP1 = generate_integer(level)

while OP2 in op2_list:
  OP2 = generate_integer(level)
```

You should also remove all relevant code around the filtering, as it is not really necessary for the exercise.